# HPQC Report Query Builder

Tags: sql, join

I am interested in solving a SQL-query puzzle which drives me nuts. I have to build a query which affects three tables. I tried to solve this via a procedure, but I guess the HPQC Report Query Builder is not able to deal with a procedure. So I have to use another solution.

Here is the 3-step problem: I identify a **bug_id** from the first table. With this id, I feed another table to get the corresponding **user_id** from the second table. As a last step, I lookup the corresponding **username** with the user_id from the second table.

```
SELECT bug_id FROM Bugs WHERE (Color='green') --> RESULT_A
SELECT link_id FROM Link WHERE (the_user = RESULT_A) --> RESULT_B
SELECT username FROM Users WHERE (user_id = RESULT_B)
```

I tried to fiddle my way through JOINS but it seems not to work. Therefore I tried to simplify the problem by using only a simple 2-step (lookup) example:

```
SELECT LINKTABLE.USERID, USERTABLE.USERNAME
FROM  LINKTABLE 
INNER JOIN USERTABLE 
ON LINKTABLE.USERID = USERTABLE.USERID;
```

HPQC reports: invalid Statements.

Is there anybody who could help me building a simple lookup query ?

**UPDATE:**

This is my solution for a join over 2 tables:

```
SELECT
 b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect,
 b.BG_USER_09 as PTR,
 b.BG_STATUS as Status,
 b.BG_SEVERITY as Severity,
 b.BG_USER_01 as Category,
 b.BG_USER_66 as Theme,
 b.BG_USER_64 as Page_Impacted,
 b.BG_DETECTION_DATE as Detected_on_Date,
 b.BG_DETECTION_VERSION as Detected_in_Version,
 l.LN_ENTITY_ID,
 l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE
FROM
 BUG b
JOIN
 LINK l
ON
 b.BG_BUG_ID = l.LN_BUG_ID
WHERE
 (b.BG_BUG_ID = 5555)
AND
 (l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TEST')
ORDER BY b.BG_BUG_ID ASC
```

Now I need to add a third information coming from another table. So there have to be 2 JOINS..

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT
 b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect,
 b.BG_USER_09 as PTR,
 b.BG_STATUS as Status,
 b.BG_SEVERITY as Severity,
 b.BG_USER_01 as Category,
 b.BG_USER_66 as Theme,
 b.BG_USER_64 as Page_Impacted,
 b.BG_DETECTION_DATE as Detected_on_Date,
 b.BG_DETECTION_VERSION as Detected_in_Version,
 t.TS_NAME as Testcase
FROM
 BUG b
JOIN LINK l ON b.BG_BUG_ID = l.LN_BUG_ID
JOIN TEST t ON l.LN_ENTITY_ID = t.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE
 (b.BG_BUG_ID = 5555)
AND
 (l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TEST')
ORDER BY b.BG_BUG_ID ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select b.bug_id, u.username as Name
from Bugs b
join Link l on b.id = l.the_user
join Users u on l.the_user = u.username
where Color = 'green'
```

Comment: I had trouble with your query and it took me 1h to figure out, that the WHERE clause must be at the end of the Statement.

Comment: -1'd. The where clause should go after the join's. This will always throw an error in SQL

Comment: @StuartBlackler Thats fair enough, I think I wrote the query before the join and then simply forgot to move the where clause!